# Wrong mime type detection in Mac / Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, heroku, mime-types, mime

I'm running Mac 10.10.3. Assume `some_file.xlsx` is a proper MS Excel file.

When I type  `file -b --mime some_file.xlsx`, I get `application/zip; charset=binary` .

But at the same time when I run this in my heroku ubuntu instance, I get `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=binary`

How can I solve this issue in my mac?

Comment: Me too I'm looking for an equivalent `mimetype` command (Ubuntu) on MacOS. 
Fore more information, I'm trying to use `file -I file_name.crt` but it returns `text/plain; charset=us-ascii` for all the certificates I tried.